Chain rule to differentiate vector fields with a connection or Lie derivative
Let $X : M \rightarrow TM$ be a smooth vector field, $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a smooth real valued function and $\gamma : [0,T] \rightarrow M$ a smooth curve in $M$.
I am interested in differentiating the real valued function,
$$X(f)(\gamma) : [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad X(f(\gamma_t)) := X(f) \Bigg\vert_{\gamma(t)}$$
where as usual $X$ acts as a differential operator on $f$ to produce a new smooth function $X(f) : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
One can easily apply the following variant of the chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dt} X(f(\gamma_t)) = \boldsymbol{d} \left[ X(f) \right] ( \dot{\gamma}_t) = \dot{\gamma}(X(f))$$
where the vector field $\dot{\gamma} : [0,T] \rightarrow TM$ hits the real function $X(f)$.
However, this "skips" differentating the individual terms $X, f$. I figured this can be achieved using a covariant derivative to differentiate the 1-form $\boldsymbol{d} f$,
$$\frac{d}{dt} X(f(\gamma_t)) = \left[ \nabla_{X} (\boldsymbol{d}f) \right] (\dot{\gamma}_t)$$
However I don't like this, since there is only 1 way to differentiate real valued functions of 1 variable, but the above formula depends on what connection to pick. In fact, I also have another choice to use a Lie derivative
$$\frac{d}{dt} X(f(\gamma_t)) = \left[ \mathcal{L}_{X} (\boldsymbol{d}f) \right] (\dot{\gamma}_t)$$
Is there anyway to differentiate $X$'s dependence on $f$?

Your notation is a bit confusing: $(Xf)(\gamma_t)$ makes sense, but once you've composed $f(\gamma_t)$ you have a function $[0,T] \to \mathbb R$ so what does $X(f(\gamma_t))$ mean?

You're right, it's a bit sloppy. I have defined it in the question, but I suppose I should have called it $X(f) (\gamma_t)$ instead.

As you say: $X(f)$ is a function from $M$ to $\mathbb R\,.$ Then $X(f)(\gamma_t)$ makes sense but $X(f(\gamma_t))$ does not. If you are willing to introduce a new vector field $Y$ of which $\gamma_t$ is an integral curve you could write
$Y(X(f))\,.$ If we write $g=X(f)$ this is nothing else than $Y(g)\,.$ Since the components of $Y$ evaluated on the curve $\gamma_t$ are $\dot\gamma^1_t\,,\dots,\dot\gamma^2_t$  this could be written as
$$\tag1
\frac d{dt}X(f)(\gamma_t)=
\frac d{dt}g(\gamma_t)=Y(g)(\gamma_t)=\dot\gamma^\nu_t\,\partial_\nu g(\gamma_t)\,.
$$
This is a number in $\mathbb R\,.$ The equality of the far LHS with the far RHS
can be seen directly without using $Y\,.$
The Lie derivative of $df$ along  $X=v^\mu\,\partial_\mu$ is the one-form
\begin{align}\tag2
{\cal L}_X(df)&=d(i_X(df))+i_X(\underbrace{ddf}_0)=d\Big(i_X\big(\underbrace{(\partial_\mu f)\,dx^\mu}_{\textstyle df}\big)\Big)=d\big(\underbrace{v^\mu\,(\partial_\mu f)}_{\textstyle g=X(f)}\big)\\[2mm]
%&=(\partial_\mu f)\,dz^\mu+z^\mu\,d(\partial_\mu f)=(\partial_\mu f)\,(\partial_\nu z^\mu)\,dx^\nu+z^\mu\,(\partial_\nu\partial_\mu f)\,dx^\nu\\[2mm]
&=\underbrace{\partial_\nu\big(v^\mu(\partial_\mu f))}_{\textstyle\partial_\nu g}\,dx^\nu=d(X(f))=dg\,.\tag3
\end{align}
If we let this one-form eat $Y$ and evaluate it on $\gamma(t)$ we do in fact get
$$
\dot\gamma^\nu_t\,\partial_\nu g(\gamma_t)
$$
which equals (1). So
$$\tag4
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}\frac d{dt}X(f)(\gamma_t)={\cal L}_X(df)(Y)(\gamma_t)\quad}
$$
where I use $Y(\gamma_t)=\dot\gamma^\nu_t\,\partial_\nu\,.$
